# The point of holedness

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality

In general relativity there is a vaguely defined notion of a spacetime having "holes", with many different definitions. Many of those were cast off when it was realized that Minkowski space also has holes under those definitions. Some of these definitions include :

- A spacetime $(M,g)$ has holes if it's locally extendible, that is, for $U$ an open set, there's an extension $(U', g')$ such that $U'$ has compact closure but $U$ doesn't (this is true of Minkowski space)
- A spacetime $(M,g)$ has holes if there exists an isometry $\phi$ of one of its achronal surface $S$ to another spacetime $(M', g')$ such that $D^+(\phi(S)) \neq \phi(D^+(S))$ (this is true of Minkowski space)
- A spacetime $(M,g)$ has holes if there exists an isometry $\phi$ of one of its achronal surface $S$ to another spacetime $(M', g')$ such that $\phi(S)$ itself is achronal and $D^+(\phi(S)) \neq \phi(D^+(S))$ (this is true of Minkowski space)

There's a few additional definitions which have not been shown to be unreasonable so far, but I wonder what the motivation for such a concept is, or at least its relation with global hyperbolicity.

Is there a spacetime which is globally hyperbolic but still has holes in a meaningful ways? What is basically an example of a spacetime with holes that could not be described in every case by another notion of causality, such as a status on the causal hierarchy or a statement on its singularities? Also is there some kind of Cauchy problem related reason for wanting hole-freeness?

Comment: *Also is there some kind of Cauchy problem related reason for wanting hole-freeness?* As an example, if we remove a point from Minkowski space, then it no longer has Cauchy surfaces. A Cauchy surface is  a surface such that every inextensible non-spacelike curve intersects the surface exactly once. With the removal of a point, we can have timelike curves that terminate on the point and never intersect a given Cauchy surface.

Comment: Would you be happy with (1) a general explanation of the physical motivation for this notion, or do you want (2) an optimal and rigorous definition of "holiness" together with a theorem proving that certain bad physical things (such as causality violations) occur if and only if there is holiness? Or do you want something in between? I can certainly provide #1.

Comment: A physical motivation would be nice, since I'm not 100% sure how it doesn't overlap with other notions, although it's hard to be sure since due to the very high number of definitions, I'm not exactly sure how (I've seen examples of holed spacetimes that are globally hyperbolic but also a proof that inextendible stably-causal spacetimes are hole-free)

Comment: *There's a few additional definitions which have not been shown to be unreasonable so far*. Could you provide a reference for that 'new and improved' definitions?

Comment: Here's a paper with some propositions : http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~bwrobert/research/NotesOnHoles.pdf